# .obj model size reduce

Tags: modeling, objects, export

I downloaded ready-made models from the Internet and some of them are 4 MB. But these dimensions are too big for me. I need to reduce their size. What I don't understand is how the hat can be 4mb. A human model is about 482 kb. I know that corners increase the size of the model. but the difference is too much. there must be something else.

summary: I want to reduce the size of an object

hat
https://ibb.co/6PyC54Q
human
https://ibb.co/PgXnvKw

Comment: The size most likely comes from the number of vertices in the model. If you reduce the number of vertices in the model (e.g. through a decimate modifier), does it reduce the size adequately?

Comment: it really works. I reduced the size of the object by 3 mb. thank you